# Query Performance with LIMIT 0

Tags: python, postgresql

My application will receive select queries submitted by users, but rather than execute it and get the full result set, at this stage, it just need the column names & types.

The users will be data analysts, so I expect a lot of hairy queries to be submitted. Submitted queries will stick around in the application and get evaluated frequently (based on a mixture of triggers & crons) as the data volume grows.

The client application is written in python & sqlalchemy-core to interact with the database.

Currently I'm appending a `LIMIT 0` at the end of the query to get just the result meta data. This is giving me acceptable results so far

Example:

query-to-be-examined:

```
SELECT * FROM users
```

probing query

```
SELECT * FROM users LIMIT 0
```

`EXPLAIN ANALYZE` returns the following result:

```
Limit  (cost=0.00..0.11 rows=1 width=646) (actual time=0.001..0.001 rows=0 loops=1)
  ->  Seq Scan on users  (cost=0.00..22457.28 rows=207728 width=646) (never executed)
Planning time: 0.067 ms
Execution time: 0.025 ms
```

Note that the `Seq Scan on users` has a note `(never executed)`.

Next I tried `LIMIT 0` on a more complicated query with the following result:

```
EXPLAIN ANALYZE
WITH blah AS (
SELECT * 
FROM users 
JOIN reservation 
  ON reservation.user_id = users.id
)
SELECT * FROM blah 
LIMIT 0

-- result:
Limit  (cost=482925.94..482925.96 rows=1 width=1955) (actual time=0.001..0.001 rows=0 loops=1)
  CTE blah
    ->  Hash Join  (cost=42094.88..482925.94 rows=1563750 width=1418) (never executed)
          Hash Cond: (reservation.user_id = users.id)
          ->  Seq Scan on reservation  (cost=0.00..96868.50 rows=1563750 width=772) (never executed)
          ->  Hash  (cost=22457.28..22457.28 rows=207728 width=646) (never executed)
                ->  Seq Scan on users  (cost=0.00..22457.28 rows=207728 width=646) (never executed)
  ->  CTE Scan on blah  (cost=0.00..31275.00 rows=1563750 width=1955) (never executed)
Planning time: 8.284 ms
Execution time: 0.113 ms
```

Again, the only costs incurred are planning time & a smaller execution time.

Questions:

1. Is it safe to assume an upper bound on the total time as being twice the planning time?
2. In Postgresql I thought CTEs were optimization fences all the time. However, with the `LIMIT 0`, the CTE's don't seem to get materialized `(never executed)`. Is that a behaviour I can rely on going forward (9.5+)
3. Is there a simpler / more efficient method to get a select query's metadata? *if I can assume point 1 above, then this is not a very important concern*
4. *anecdotally, what is the largest planning time you have observed on a SELECT query?*
5. I'm fairly certain that even as the data volume grows in the underlying tables, I can assume the planning time to be similar for the same query. Is there a case where this would not hold true?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. I *think* that execution time will be about constant in most cases, with the notable exception of data modifying CTEs (see below).
2. If the CTE never gets used, it is not executed. The exception to this rule is if there is a data modifying statement in the CTE; in this case, the CTE is always executed.
3. I don't think there is a better way in PL/Python. If you write a C function you could probably prepare the statement and then get its result columns, but it's probably non-trivial as well.
4. No cool story to share...
5. The planning time is independent of the size of the tables.

Comment: Thanks Laurenz, 2,3,4,5 makes perfect sense. For 1. I was wondering if you could provide an example query & explain analyze with limit 0 that would have an execution time greater than planning time.

Comment: Oh, I misunderstood. I though you meant it would constitute an upper bound for the execution time *without* the `LIMIT 0`. I have modified part 1 of the answer.